# PHP does not receive values from post form

Tags: php, forms, post

**CASE 1**

if i put this , i can´t receive the end value from input

```
<?php echo $_POST[tester-test-t]; ?>

<form action="" method="post"> <input type="text" name="tester-test-t" value="" /> <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Sender" /> </form>
```

**CASE 2**

if i put this i can receive value from form

```
<?php echo $_POST['tester-test-t']; ?>

<form action="" method="post"> <input type="text" name="tester-test-t" value="" /> <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Sender" /> </form>
```

**CASE 3**

And finally if i put this , also i can received the value from POST form , as you can see i puto "_" and not the same as in the case 1 "-"

```
echo $_POST[tester_test_t]; 

<form action="" method="post"> <input type="text" name="tester-test-t" value="" /> <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Sender" /> </form>
```

The question it´s about , which it´s the problem for not receive the value from post form in the case 1 and yes , in the other cases with '' and with "-"

Regards and thank´s

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: "Why is $foo[bar] wrong?": https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar

Comment: Neither case 1 nor case 3 works for me. Are you sure you don't have some additional code in your case 3 test that you didn't copy into the question?

Answer (score 3):

**Case 1:**

`tester-test-t` means

> take value of constant `tester`, substract value of constant `test`, substract value of constant `t`.

The result of substraction will be the key in a `$_POST` array.

Do you have such constants in your code? Surely, you **don't**.

**Case 2:**

`'tester-test-t'` is just a string. And string key `'tester-test-t'` exists in your `$_POST`

**Case 3:**

`tester_test_t` is considered a **constant** again. Do you have constant `tester_test_t` defined? Surely, you **don't**.

And to understand what's going wrong in your code - use [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) (thanks @Fred -ii-)

Comment: This works in localhost but not in server , i don´t know if the problem it´s php configuration or whats because in local works , regards

Comment: @SergioRSergi your POST array keys should always be encased in single quotes so, as referenced by u_mulder, they are not accidentally used mathematically or otherwise incorrectly. Also always reference your array values as per **Case 2**.

Comment: Ok understand , but why works with "_" and don´t works with "-" , and in localhost with xamp works perfectly and in server with php 5.3 don´t works , wich it´s the problem in these cases

Comment: It's not matter of `-`. You can have them in array keys **if you use them right way**. See "Why is $foo[bar] wrong?" here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar

Answer (score -1):

It's likely to be something to do with character encoding, and how the - gets treated as it is passed into an http request as the form gets submitted.  The - is likely getting encoded in a certain way and causing you problems.

A simple solution is getting rid of the hyphens in your field name, so change name="tester-test-t" to something like name="TesterTestT".

Personally I prefer to specify an action="" with the name of another .php script to do the processing of the form.  I find submitting the form back to itself can get confusing.

Rgds